# Getting error when trying to use aws javascript sdk v3 with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3

I have a function that reads a file from s3 bucket:

```
export const s3Client = new S3Client({region: 'us-east-1'});

export async function readFromS3(client: S3Client) {
    const input = {
        Bucket: 'foo',
        Key: bar/key.json'
    }
    try {
        console.log(`reading from s3: ${input.Bucket}`)
        const command = new GetObjectCommand(input)
        const response = await client.send(command)
        if (!response.Body) {
            throw new Error(`Body is undefined when reading data from bucket: ${input.Bucket} and key: ${input.Key}`)
        }
        const body = await response.Body.transformToString()
        return JSON.parse(body)
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`Error reading data from s3 bucket: ${input.Bucket} ${error}`)
    }
}
```

I am using it in aws lambda handler:

```
export const handler = Create(
    config,
    (event, payloads) => {
        // Download the file from S3
        const result = readFromS3(s3Client)

        return payloads.map( (item) => {
                    result.then(function(result){
                        console.log(result[0])
                    }).catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                }
            }

            return event(url: url})
        })
    }
)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "Error reading data from s3 bucket: foo Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See [https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported"](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported%22)